# pandas iterate over many dataframe and create list of occurance per key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, data-munging

I have the few hundreds of dataframe with the same sturcture.
I want to aggregate per key as follows:
For the list columns - create a list of lists (where each list is the value of specific dataframe)
For example in case of 2 datarames:

```
df1 =  
Key  C1.  C2. C3
 A  [1,2]  6   b
 B  [6,1]  9   c

df2 = 
Key  C1   C2   C3
 B  [5,8]  2    t
 A  [7,2]  3    z

df_agg =  
   Key      C1          C2        C3 
    A  [[1,2],[7,2]]   [6,3]    [b,z]  
    B  [[6,1],[5,8]]   [9,2]    [c,t]
```

Please notice I have few hundreds: df1, df2, ... dfn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Solution for list of DataFrames - use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and aggregate `list`:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]

df = pd.concat(dfs).groupby('Key', as_index=False).agg(list)
print (df)
  Key                C1      C2      C3
0   A  [[1, 2], [7, 2]]  [6, 3]  [b, z]
1   B  [[6, 1], [5, 8]]  [9, 2]  [c, t]
```

Comment: Please see edit, I have many dataframes

Comment: @Cranjis - Are `key`s unique per DataFrame?

Comment: All dataframe have the exact same shape, each with 8 columns and 199 rows - that are 199 unique values for Key